# Flyway - Flyway Schema Creation issue

Tags: flyway

Just want to know whoever is working with flyway if they are getting this

```
<< Flyway Schema Creation >>
```

with version set to 0.

It suddenly started appearing on my metadata table and I am not sure where it came from and how I can run mugrates without it appearing again

Answer (score 4):

This means flyway created the schema(s) you specified in **`flyway.schemas`**. Calling **`clean()`** will also drop the schemas themselves and not just the objects they contain.

Comment: This is a bit flaky I am afraid, it occurs very randomly, at times i get this at times i dont, sometime i am required to swap schemas in order this to disappear. :(

Comment: If you have multiple schemas in flyway.schemas this will appear when Flyway found all of them to be missing and created them for you. As soon as one schema is present, none will be created.